# UIView manipulation for collage like picture in high resolution

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, image-manipulation, core-image

I'm currently working on a collage application where users can combine multiple images into one collage (in a grid like layout, like 2x2). I worked on a couple of examples where coders used a UIView to which the images were added as Subviews. The subviews itself are zoomable and scrollable, so that the images can be adjustet inside their boxes.

The results are then exported as a JPEG reprensentation. While the results are okish, the problem is that output from the UIView only is as big as its screen size (640x640 for a 2x Screen on an iPhone 4 / 5). I was wondering if there would be better way to maybe compose a higher resolution image from the original image sources with consideration of the changes made in the view.

[The View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DeU7A.png)